# How to access row with certain datetime?

Tags: python, dataframe

If I have a database with an index comprising of datetimes in this format: Y-m-d H:M:S, how can I extract a row with an index that matches a certain date and time?

I've tried this:

```
df.loc[df.index == '2011-01-01 00:00:00']
```

And:

```
df['2011-01-01 00:00:00']
```

But the above simply returns -->  `Index: []`

Any help would be appreciated.

My database looks like this:
`datetime  ...  season_weather_mean_count`

`0      2011-01-01 00:00:00  ...                 126.781694`

`1      2011-01-01 01:00:00  ...                 126.781694`

`2      2011-01-01 02:00:00  ...                 126.781694`

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(df)` to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
 df[df['datetime'] == 'date_you want_to_select']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following for getting the required row. For example

```
mask = (df['index'] == "2011-01-01 00:00:00")
print(df.loc[mask])
```

Answer (score 0):

for your case you can do this

```
df[df.index == '2011-01-01 00:00:00']
```